# Autocomplete is active on select values that I dont want Jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I used the auto completion feature and it works well. Now I want an autocompletion that is done according to the value of my select 
field.

When the value of my select is "editeur", "auteur" and "sujet" autocomplete works well but it continues to be active on the values ​​of my select which should not be affected by auto completion. I do not understand why...

The values of my select are: titre, sujet, auteur, annee_edition, editeur, nouveautes

I dont want "annee_edition", "titre" and "nouveautes" to have autocomplete

**My script:**

```
$(document).on("change", "#triAdmin", function(e) {

$("#champs_recherche_ad‌​min").autocomplete( "enable" );
var val = $(this).val();
  if(val == "auteur"){
$("#champs_recherche_admin").autocomplete({
    source: baseurl+"admin/admin_controller/autocompleteAuteur", 
    minLength : 1
  }
);
}
else if(val == "editeur"){
$("#champs_recherche_admin").autocomplete({
    source: baseurl+"admin/admin_controller/autocompleteEditeur", 
    minLength : 1
  }
);
}   
else if(val == "sujet"){
$("#champs_recherche_admin").autocomplete({
    source: baseurl+"admin/admin_controller/autocompleteSujet", 
    minLength : 1
  }
 );
  }     
else{
  $("#champs_recherche_ad‌​min").autocomplete( "disable" );
}
}).change();
```

**Edit**:
I added:

```
$("#champs_recherche_ad‌​min").autocomplete( "disable" );(at the end)
```

and

```
$("#champs_recherche_ad‌​min").autocomplete( "enable" ); (at the top)
```

to TRY to enable and disable the autocomplete...

Comment: Your code needs some serious refactorization for sure but i guess you need in a else condition of `change` handler to use: `if($("#champs_recherche_admin").data('ui-autocomplete'))$("#champs_recherche_admin").autocomplete( "disable" );` and re-enable when needed. But you should just switch source option on the fly

Comment: I removed this line of code because it was not relevant to my issue

Comment: Sorry, which line? Can you provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your first comment

Comment: I understand that I have to enable en disable the autocomplete... but why do you use .data('ui-autocomplete')? I'm new with Jquery ;)

Comment: It is just a check if autocomplete plugin is already 'bound' to element because otherwise `$("#champs_recherche_ad‌​min").autocomplete( "disable" );` could throw an error. That's said, i don't know that much jQuery UI and maybe this is already handled internally so you could not have to check for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't enable en disable the autocomplete properly. I had to destroy the auto completion for fields that should not be Autocomplete!

```
$(document).on("change", "#triAdmin", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  // si la valeur du select est nouveauté désactiver le champs de recherche
  $("#champs_recherche_admin").prop("disabled", (val == "nouveautes"));
  if(val == "auteur"){
    $("#champs_recherche_admin").autocomplete({
        source: baseurl+"admin/admin_controller/autocompleteAuteur", 
        minLength : 1
      }
    );
  }
  else if(val == "editeur"){
    $("#champs_recherche_admin").autocomplete({
        source: baseurl+"admin/admin_controller/autocompleteEditeur", 
        minLength : 1
      }
    );
  }
  else if(val == "sujet"){
    $("#champs_recherche_admin").autocomplete({
        source: baseurl+"admin/admin_controller/autocompleteSujet", 
        minLength : 1
      }
    );
  }
  else if(val == "annee_edition"||(val == "titre")){
    $('#champs_recherche_admin').autocomplete();
    $( "#champs_recherche_admin" ).autocomplete( "destroy" );
  }
}).change();
```